# Averaging four pixels of image yields wonky colors

Tags: java, image-processing, colors

I have an image of specified height and width to be shrunk down 1/4th. My method for doing so has been to take 4 pixels (so (0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1) for example), grab the RGB values of each and then average out the RGB values and inject it to a new image as one pixel (so those four pixel co-ords mentioned earlier will become (0,0) of a new image).

It works, sort of; I get some color wonkiness in the result.

[image]

The left is the original image, and to the right is it processed through the method above. I can't for the life of me figure out why the colors are screwy.

For what it's worth, I'm using the below methods:

```
getPixel();
getColor();
setColor();
```

And the RGB values are grabbed separately via `getRed()`, etc. These are stored as integers.

Comment: What happens if you do something like `r = r + 0.25*color.getRed()` instead of averaging later? You may be encountering a cast of either integer overflow (ie: the sum is so big it is bigger than the largest value an integer can hold, and it overflows to a negative number or re-starts at zero) or integer saturation (ie: the language detects you are going to have an integer overflow, so any further additions just result in the same value). This method is slightly less efficient as you do more divisions per loop, but it is safer.

Comment: useful reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_arithmetic

Comment: How are `r,g`, and `b` declared?

Comment: The range of an integer should be well beyond 1024, though. For what it's worth @Dogbert, though; I had tried `r = r + 0.25*color.getRed()` and equivalent for green and blue, and my output is a wonderful canvas of rainbow static noise.

Comment: @Henry, defined as integers with starting values 0.

Comment: what are the declarations for all your variables? You should check the documentation for all the methods to see if there's something quirky.

Comment: You should reset r,g,b to 0 inside of the first two loops.

Comment: I've checked the documentation for `.getRed()`, the other color ones, `.getPixel()`, and `.setColor()` and I'm working within the parameters within.

Comment: What API is this? A java.awt.Color will return RGB values in the range of 0 - 255 with getRed/getBlue/getGreen methods. There will not be overflow.

Comment: The Color type is only valid on [0,255], so far as I can see: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/31datatype/  So, even if the data type is int, the values could likely be out-of-range.

Comment: What api is Picture from? it doesn't appear in the standard libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where do you reset the variables r, g, b?

b is used both for color and to iterate?

Comment: Good catch, but fortunately the above isn't code I'm working with, just rewritten. In my actual code I don't use b at all, I use other variables. I did fix the code in the OP, though. The error was a silly one; I forgot to reset the RBG values. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like overflow. What data type are R, G and B?  If they're 8-bit unsigned, convert to 16-bit unsigned before adding and shifting. An average will come out in the proper range, since an average cannot exceed the range from the smallest value to the largest value given, but the intermediate sum will easily do so.

If you don't mind slower processing, convert to floats, add and divide by 4, then convert back. A whole lot more math can be done such as logarithms, hyperbolic tangents (my fave), etc.  But your question does not suggest any need for such things.  It is the nearly universal cure, however, for overflows when the math gets heavy.

Answer (score 2):

You never reset `r,g,b` in your loop, so the next pixel isn't getting the right value(in *any* case). It's adding the four pixels to the last pixel result, then dividing by 4.

Since there are five numbers added together, you're getting a creep up in your color values. For instance, if the previous pixel red value was `240`, and the next four are `220,220,220,220`, you get an "average" of `280`, even though all four pixels are `220`. The next pixel is then messed up even further, etc.

That's why you get a "creep" to overflow. When one goes over 255, you get overflow when the numbers are combined back together with `setColor()`. You can see clearly where each byte is overflowing. First come the red(in the cyan areas), then the yellow drops out(in the dark blueish).

Just make sure you reset `r,g,b` to zero after you call `setColor()` and it should be fine.

Comment: Cheers, this was it. You and Joel have saved Russel Crow.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare r,g,b as ***long*** unsigned int.

```
long unsigned int r,g,b;
```

In spots where the color could be (255,0,0) and if the format is RGBA. The **R** component is bit-shifted 24 bits to use up the most significant 8 bits. Even multiplying it by 2 could potentially cause an overflow of the unsigned 32 bit int. Using 64 bit(signed or unsigned) would solve this problem

Comment: To elaborate, this answer is suggesting your problem is numeric overflow. As you add, your sum is wrapping back to negative values. Declaring r,g,b values as long gives you a higher upper range, preventing numeric overflow. However, declaring r,g,b as an int instead of a long would work fine.